# How can I get lines to break automatically using the LaTeX listings package?

Tags: listings

I am using the `listings` package to include sample Perl source code in LaTeX. I included the package with `\usepackage{listings}`, and used the following code:

```
\lstset{language=Perl}
\lstset{commentstyle=\textit}
\lstset{frame=shadowbox}
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left]
$subject = "<owamp:subject xmlns:owamp=\"http://ggf.org/ns/nmwg/tools/owamp/2.0/\" id=\"subject\">\n";
\end{lstlisting}
```

The resulting output is:

[image: Screenshot of the output]

The line doesn't seem to breaking, but I read that lines break automatically when using the `listings` package. This line is the entire PDF snapshot of the code.

Am I doing anything wrong as far as the code is concerned?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `breaklines=true`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings} 
\lstset{language=Perl}
\lstset{commentstyle=\textit}
\lstset{frame=shadowbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left, breaklines=true]
$subject = "<owamp:subject xmlns:owamp=\"http://ggf.org/ns/nmwg/tools/owamp/2.0/\" id=\"subject\">\n";
\end{lstlisting}\end{document}
```